# VBA Excel Mark selection but copy next column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy range from B2 to the last filled in Cell in the column. However there are breaks in the column that causes the xlDown function to stop prematurely, therefore I want to copy column A from A2 to the last filled in cell instead, since column A doesn't have any breaks in it.

Is it possible to somehow do this, and then offset the selected Range by One column, giving me the data I am after?

I am thinking something like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End (xlDown)
```

But how do I cause an offset so I end up with Range B2:xlDown (but the xlDown is the position of the previous selection of column A)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

.Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1).Select

End With
```

You can use Offset Function, to shift the Column. Also Change `Select` to Copy or whatever else do you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go down from the top, go up from the bottom:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,2), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp)).Copy
```

We use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(` to define a range by 2 corners of a rectangle.  Our first corner is Cell B2, a.k.a. Row 2 Column 2: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,2)`

The other corner will be the bottommost cell in Column B with data in it.  So, we start with the *very* bottom of the *entire* column, and move **up** until we hit data:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp)
```

Then, we copy the resulting rectangular range: `).Copy`